# Image should change on mouse-over, using jQuery and jCoverflip

Tags: jquery, html

For designing a UI page, I am using jCoverflip for image carousel. Here functionality is like clicking on image will bring the selected image in larger form.

But I am thinking to put this functionality via mouse over; I am not getting a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change line `542` of `jquery.jcoverflip.js` from:

```
this.element.click( proxy( this, this._clickItem ) );
```

to

```
this.element.mouseover( proxy( this, this._clickItem ) );
```

Comment: Awesome Shot ... Joe .. +1 For Saving my Day ... I hope you will complete 1000 as soon as